# dll in php "the specified module could not be found"

Tags: php, config, php-ini

I am having trouble with PHP extensions. I am trying to run a script and nothing happens then I checked my error log and here is what I got:

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\ext\php_oci8.dll' - The specified module could not be found. in Unknown on line 0
```

same goes for following files:

```
 php_oci8_11g.dll
 php_pdo_oci.dll
 php_sybase_ct.dll
 php_com_dotnet.dll
```

every file except php_com_dotnet.dll was installed with PHP installation, all the files are enabled in php.ini configuration. After researching online I saw some people said that it has to be copied to system32 or sysWOW64 folder, which I did without success. Then I tried to register them using regsvr32 in cmd and I am getting error for every single file:

```
"The module name_of_the_module.dll failed to load"
```

I don't understand what am I doing wrong.

Server configuration is Windows 2008 R2 64bit, IIS7, PHP 5.3.27

Comment: This question would probably be more appropriate on http://ServerFault.com/

Answer (score 6):

On Windows, I solved these kind of problems by adding the path specified in 'extension_dir' (in php.ini) to the value of PATH system environment variable.

Comment: Thanks! you are right. instantclient path need to be in the global env PATH. :)

Answer (score 4):

Check your `extension_dir` in your `php.ini`, it has to point to the correct directory.

```
# X:/path/to/php.ini

# On Windows
extension_dir = "ext"
```

Comment: Here are my settings:

; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
; http://php.net/extension-dir
; extension_dir = "./"
; On windows:
extension_dir = "C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\ext\"

Comment: My bad, corrected my answer (the path should be relative according to ini documentation).