# Installing gRPC for localhost

Tags: xampp, google-cloud-firestore, grpc

I'm working with PHP library of [Google Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart), it requires me to install and enable the [gRPC extension](https://cloud.google.com/php/grpc).. I've read the guide which says

> Windows users can download and enable DLLs from [PECL](https://pecl.php.net/package/gRPC). Support for
>   Windows is experimental

In the [PECL](https://pecl.php.net/package/gRPC) site I can see many links to `tgz` and `DLL` files but without any explanation of how to use or activate them in the XAMPP as a localhost

Answer (score 26, accepted):

With the help of [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.windows.php).. I found that these steps will activate **gRPC**

1. From [PECL](https://pecl.php.net/package/gRPC) site (or [windows.php.net](https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/grpc/) which has the exact same files) .. choose DLL of the latest stable release
   [image]
2. According to the PHP version you have :

   - For XAMPP with **PHP > 7.2.15** .. choose **Thread Safe (TS) x64**
   - For older XAMPP .. choose **Thread Safe (TS) x86**
3. Download the ZIP file then extract its contents
4. Copy the `php_grpc.dll` file to the **extensions folder** in XAMPP (you can find the path in `php.ini`) .. in my case it was `extension_dir="C:\xampp\php\ext"`
5. Enable the extension in your `php.ini` file :

   - For **PHP version 7.2** and up .. add `extension=grpc`
   - For **older PHP** .. add `extension=php_grpc.dll`
6. Restart XAMPP and the extension will be activated as showed in `phpinfo()`

[image]

Comment: i know this is old , but I'm trying to do the same but i cant seem to find any php_grpc.dll files or anything can you give more info on what to do?

Comment: @Innervisions you can find the `php_grpc.dll` file in content of the ZIP you downloaded .. I've updated the answer to make it more clear

Comment: I did everything as you said and i still don't see it, i hate this extension so much...

Comment: do i need to download the other rar thats not the DLL and if i do where do i place it?

Comment: @innervisions no, it won't be useful, what is the link to the zip file you downloaded which should contain the DLL file ?

Comment: the 1.13.0 version  non-thread safe but i tried all for the 7.2 php version none of them worked

Comment: @Innervisions I've uploaded the `php_grpc.dll` file for you.. so you can download it directly https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Kv2PZJu2fxD92vcXHOptwV_hmWKAnjhG/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Doesn't work with that file.

I followed all of your instructions , i just don't see the extension  when i write check phpinfo()  , when i try to install something with the console i get an error that it can't find grpc module

I get this:
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_grpc.dll' (tried: D:\Xamp\php\ext\php_grpc.dll (The specified module could not be found.), D:\Xamp\php\ext\php_php_grpc.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: sorry about that.. check this link, hope it can solve the problem for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19772356/dll-in-php-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found

Comment: don't forget, wamp, xampp have 2 version php.ini file, we must add extension in all php.ini file, if not, it does not work while downloading cloud-firestore library via composer

Comment: As instructed, I downloaded the php_grpc-1.37.0-7.3-ts-vc15-x64, unzipped and copied the .dll file into php/ext folder, added extension=php_grpc in the php.ini file, restarted the xampp and it worked fine. I am using PHP 7.3.9 on Windows 10 OS.

Answer (score 5):

I would like to add answer for 7.4.4 PHP Version,

I downloaded `php_grpc-1.27.0-7.4-ts-vc15-x64.zip` from this link https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/grpc/1.27.0/

Then I copied pasted `php_grpc.dll` to C:\xampp\php\ext folder

In next step I opened php.ini under Dynamic extentions added extension=grpc

And then restarted and it was working fine.

Comment: Helped me. Windows 10, XAMP with PHP 7.4

Comment: Just a correction : "Extensions" spelling is incorrect. So it would be "Dynamic Extensions"

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 | PHP 7.1

I tried to debug this for 4 hours and could not find the right solution. I later on realized that besides the grpc extension, there were some other extensions also like oci which threw the same error when I tried to uncomment those (while keeping grpc commented) and running any php command like php --ini

On some other forum I read that a user had to manually install PHP using windows installer and then install DLL. I thought I'll try that but I could not find an MSI so I downloaded the latest PHP zip installer from https://windows.php.net/download/ I chose the x64 version for php 7.1.

Please note that I did not install this downloaded PHP but I noticed it had a php7.dll
I had used dependency walker from http://www.dependencywalker.com/ to check the dependencies of the php_grpc.dll and found php7.dll as a dependency.

So what I did was to copy both PHP7.dll and php_grpc.dll to system32 and then I tried to install that DLL. I ran a command prompt as Admin and navigated to C:\windows\system32 and executed the command regsvr32 php_grpc.dll (Please note that this does not work without PHP7.dll being present in the same folder - or at least it did not work for me). Upon execution, I got a message that the DLL was loaded but entry point was not found. At this time when I executed php --ini again (I also had php_grpc.dll loaded to ext folder under the XAMPP php folder) I got a new error finally which said that the module being loaded was Non thread safe (NTS) whereas PHP was TS (Thread Safe). So I went to PECL, downloaded the TS version of the grpc plugin for PHP7.1 and pasted the dll file to both system32 and also the ext folder. I ran the regsvr32 /U php_grpc.dll command which uninstalls and reinstalls the DLL i believe (I am not sure if this step made any difference but I am mentioning it here because I had performed this step before calling php --ini)

After this, finally php --ini ran  without any issues. I was able to use the composer command to successfully download the dependencies for cloud-firestore. It was a waste of 4 precious hours but I hope this helps someone else.

NOTE: Instead of downloading from PECL, I downloaded the grpc zip from https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/grpc/

I don't know if this is different but it was the link mentioned on the installation site for Windows installation of PHP. Also someone else has that link here. I took the latest build which was 1.24.0 at the time of this post. And I chose the Thread Safe Version.

The reason I chose the thread safe version is because of the error that I received of version mismatch. You can also check your version by executing "php -i" in console which returns same info as phpinfo(); Copy and paste the output in some text editor and search for PHP Extension Build. below is what I saw

PHP Extension Build => API20160303,TS,VC14

Note, it is TS aka thread safe. So unlike other posts on the internet where folks downloaded non thread safe version of grpc, I downloaded threadsafe and it worked.

Comment: You comment help me, thanks. I was get NTS version...

Answer (score 1):

Please download grpc extension zip from here

https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/grpc/1.10.0/

accorging to your php version (My PHP version is 7.2.6 and x86 architecture xampp) I downloaded php_grpc-1.10.0-7.2-ts-vc15-x86.zip

after downloading extract zip file copy php_grpc.dll in e.g C:\xampp\php\ext folder

open php.ini under Dynamic extentions add extension=grpc

restart your apache server for checking open up cmd and type php -m it will show you all the extension enabled.

Comment: This answer works for me, my php version is `7.2.11`. I tried above accepted answer which was not working, i am not saying that one is wrong but this answered solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. open phpinfo of your setup and search for `Architecture` and `Thread Safety` there.

   ```
    For me `Architecture` value was `x64` and `Thread Safety` value was `enabled`
   ```
2. Go to [pecl website](https://pecl.php.net/package/grpc) and search for `DLL` in Downloads column and click on `DLL` link. It will list different DLL Lists, select one suitable to you.

   ```
   For me I have to select "7.4 Thread Safe (TS) x64" as I am using PHP 7.4.x, Thread Safety is "enabled" and Architecture is "X64".
   ```
3. Copy DLL file from downloaded Zip and paste it in ext directory.

   ```
   ext directory can be found in phpinfo - search for "extension_dir" in phpinfo.
   ```
4. open php.ini

   ```
   Path of php.ini can be found in phpinfo - search for "Loaded Configuration File" in phpinfo.
   ```
5. Add `extension=grpc` anywhere in php.ini

   ```
   Generally it is better to add it under "Dynamic Extensions" section so that you can see all your extensions at one place.
   ```
6. Restart your server -> open phpinfo -> search for "grpc" it should display a section for grpc.

[image]

> Note: All answers almost suggested similar solution, but they didn't
> work for me. the reason could be, I got confused with "Architecture"
> and "Thread Safe" thing which you can easily check in phpinfo as I
> mentioned above.

*Sharing screenshot of my phpinfo for your reference.*
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For windows modern Xampp have as syntax in php.ini
extension=php_grpc

no need .dll as extension in trail

Answer (score 0):

My PHP version is 7.2.

I downloaded and uploaded `php_grpc.dll` inside my `xampp/php/ext/php_grpc.dll` and added a code in `php.init`, `extension=grpc` (on latest version you don't need to add php_ and .dll), then I restart Xampp

Now terminal says

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'grpc' (tried: E:\xampp\php\ext\grpc (The specified module could not be found.), E:\xampp\php\ext\php_grpc.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
>
> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - google/cloud-firestore v1.6.2 requires ext-grpc * -> the requested PHP extension grpc is missing from your system.
>       - google/cloud-firestore v1.6.1 requires ext-grpc * -> the requested PHP extension grpc is missing from your system.
>       - google/cloud-firestore v1.6.0 requires ext-grpc * -> the requested PHP extension grpc is missing from your system.
>       - Installation request for google/cloud-firestore ^1.6 -> satisfiable by google/cloud-firestore[v1.6.0, v1.6.1, v1.6.2].
>
> To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
>       - E:\xampp\php\php.ini
>     You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
>
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

Comment: This does not appear to be an answer. If it is an answer please could you reword is De Hams so it is clearly such. Thanks.

Comment: No this is a question, finally solve use the php_grpc.dll from this link https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/grpc/1.10.0/

Comment: @DeHams Thank you, i downloaded the threadsafe x64 version and it worked for me