# How to properly install and run grpc with xampp and php

Tags: php, xampp, grpc

Am working with  php applications and the library that I want to use requires

1.) GRPC extension

2.) PHP >= 7.0

3.) Install gRPC extension

pecl install grpc

4.) Then add **grpc.so** to php.ini

The SO link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50222772/installing-grpc-for-localhost 
I found here suggest the the use of grpc.dll

Am running xampp on WINDOW 7.
My only problem is how do I run pecl install grpc on xampp.
Again where do I get grpc.so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download pre-compiled grpc extension for windows from the PECL website: http://pecl.php.net/package/grpc. Click on the DLL icons.