# PHP cannot find php_grpc.dll extension

Tags: php, grpc

Good day! I am new to web application development but I am familiar with PHP. I am hoping to develop a web application while using Google Firebase so I installed `tatter/firebase` through composer (I also followed everything from the documentations). While installing `tatter/firebase` in my project folder, the command tells me that PHP cannot find the `php_grpc.dll` file even if it exists in the right folder location and enabled it in `php.ini`.

I need serious and immediate help, and I can't find any solutions to this on the web.

This is the screenshot of the command window in `Git Bash`
[image]

This is the folder containing the DLL file:
[image]

This is the ini file:

[image]

Running the composer setup again and changing the `php.exe` to the xampp one, and the error is much worse.

This is the error everytime I am starting Apache serve:
[image]

Still related to `php_grpc.dll`

Comment: [For windows OS] Add this line in your php.ini file:  `extension=php_grpc.dll` - see the [offical_documentation](https://cloud.google.com/php/grpc#windows_2) please

Comment: @KenLee I tried it just now, but still, the error exists. Any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: Make sure you re-start your system after updating php.ini

Comment: @KenLee I just restarted my system, and tried installing tatter/firebase again but the error still exists

Comment: Does this resolves your issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50222772/installing-grpc-for-localhost/50222981

Comment: @Riosant I already followed this before posting my own question. In short, the existing solution did not work on my end :(

Comment: A typical xampp php.ini contains lines for extension like `extension=xxxx.dll` (most of them remarked so will look like `;extension=xxxx.dll` ). Please see picture in this [SO_post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869521/how-can-i-enable-php-extension-intl) . Hence, I am quite doubtful whether you have amended a correct php.ini in your system.

Comment: @KenLee So I have run the composer setup again to change which `php.exe` it can communicate to. I have changed it to the `php.exe` of xampp but then the error is much worse than before

Comment: You error shows that the system is trying to load the DLL (so one step forward already -- instead of saying unable to load) , but find that there is no related entry point for a particular procedure. So (1) check whether the dll is corrupted (and / or is the correct version). and (2) if still in doubt, make sure all the things (xampp, dll) are up-to-date

Comment: @KenLee I just recently re-downloaded and re-installed xampp and the DLL. I am pretty sure that all of what I need is in **correct** and **updated** versions.

Comment: Did you try installing composer with --ignore-platform-req=ext-grpc ? (i.e.,  use `composer require tatter/firebase  --ignore-platform-req=ext-grpc` )

Comment: @KenLee yes but that prevents me from having access to the firebase libraries since gRPC is required to connect the PHP and Google Firebase

Comment: OK, then visit this link: https://pecl.php.net/package/gRPC and choose the version (I believe the latest , stable one), click "DLL" (since you are using Win OS) , and choose the one suitable for your PHP version, and re-download the correct DLL (if you do not know your sytem architecture then try them one-by-one) and re-try

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been bothering me these past few days, and the solution is simple. I am not entirely sure if it is going to work for the others but I installed a downgraded version of XAMPP (8.1.1 before, now 7.4), and it magically worked.

I will thank Ken Lee for helping me with this problem. I deeply appreciate the effort!