# Xampp is skipping the php_grpc.dll file in ext folder. "Unable to load dynamic library 'grpc'"

Tags: php, google-cloud-firestore, xampp, laravel-8, grpc

I have been developing a laravel website. I have integrated google cloud firestore to it, and it required me to install and enable the grpc extension. I have been developing with it for a month now and everything is working fine. But out of nowhere, when I was about to continue the development, an error popped out when I started xampp/apache, something about vcruntime140.ddl missing from my system (i don't remember deleting anything like that, as I rarely delete things from my system). I downloaded the missing file and copied it to the required folder. Then I restarted xampp again, then it showed me this error:

> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'grpc' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_grpc.dll (The specified module could not be found), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_C:\xampp\php\ext\php_grpc.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on
> line 0.

I have scoured the internet for all the possible solutions to this. I made sure there's a php_grpc.dll in the ext folder, the grpc extension enabled in php.ini, uninstalled and reinstalled xampp, checked the accurate version, and tried different versions of the dll. But nothing still worked for me. It's as if the grpc extension dll file is invisible in the ext folder, but it's actually there. I've been stuck with this warning/error for three days now, we have a defense for this system in the following weeks but it's still isn't finished.

I am not sure where the problem comes from, but I'm sure it started when I got the error about the vcruntime140.dll file, so maybe it's related to that. I hope someone has an answer for this, it would really be helpful for me. Thank you very much!

Comment: In your php.ini use extension=php_grpc without the dll extension and make sure the php_grpc .dll is in xampp/php/ext

Comment: Still not working :(

Comment: I also tried many variations of naming the extension in the  php.ini file like grpc, php_grpc.dll, the whole path to the file, php_grpc, and still nothing worked. I think it has something to do with vcruntime140.dll because the grpc extension had been unable to be loaded ever since the vcrutime140 error

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50222772/installing-grpc-for-localhost

Comment: thanks for replying! i kinda lost hope already and just gonna start from scratch with my sister's laptop but i'm still trying the solutions from that link